# How to execute user-submitted JS code (project) securely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, sandbox

I would like to **execute user-submitted `JS` files** safely in my own Node.js application. The user can submit multiple files which can be required and executed by their `index.js` file which is triggered from my node process.

I have looked into some sandboxing solutions but they either limit the required capabilities or end up breaking the sandbox once a file is "required".

I have looked into vm, vm2, eval etc.

I'd like to restrict access to global variables like `process` and also restrict access to certain node libraries.

Comment: a more concrete use case would be preferred for this kind of question. fyi, sandboxing on most case do give up access to certain capability (especially direct file read/write). also, didnt `vm` docs says *"The `node:vm` module is not a security mechanism. **Do not use it to run untrusted code.**"* which you should abide.

Comment: When you say "execute user-submitted JS files *in* my own Node.js application", you seem to want some interaction between the two (what purpose should it serve otherwise?). How shall this interaction happen? Via a common persistency (file system, database)? Or does your application call a function provided by the user and evaluate its return value?

Answer (score 0):

If packages such as `vm2` don't satisfy you, I think nothing in node.js will satisfy you. One option if you're running on linux is to use `chroot` (either using the [chroot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chroot) module or by spawning it with [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options)), which would let you full control over the environment the untrusted code is executed in.

Answer (score 0):

You should try JavaScript v8 engine isolates. They’re more restricted and might be missing some functionality but they deliver the level of security necessary when handing untrusted code.
This https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm should give you the right interface to run user code and even extend default v8 features